# How to send mail every quarter till expiry date using sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

How to send mail every quarter till expiry date using sharepoint 2010 designer workflow.
My requirement goes like this. I have a field Expiry Date, I need to send mail to some users every quarter till it reaches the expiry date.

For Example:

Start Date :1st Jan 2013 and Expiry date is 1st jan 2015, I need to send a mail on 1st April 2013, 1st July 2013, 1st Oct 2013 and 1st Dec 2013. Even for year 2014 too.

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following,

1. Create a SharePoint Designer (SPD) workflow
2. Select your task list
3. Set it to run on Create
4. Click Next

In the Actions section add these three actions:

- Add time to date
- Pause until date
- Send email

My example looks like this after the properties are set:

```
Add -7 days to Tasks:Due Date (Output to Variable: ReminderDate)
    then Pause until Variable: Reminder Date
    then Email this message    (you can hard code the address or use the assigned to... )
```

Notes for this very simple example:

- If someone edits the task and sets a new due date, this workflow will still send the reminder based on the old date.
- It does not check to see if the Due Date is at least two days in the future.

Ref: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acb12dd2-d6a5-4b7e-b233-037558bfa2e5/start-workflow-x-days-before-expiry-date?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SharePoint Designer workflow "Pause Until" or "Pause For" action.  Microsoft touches on them briefly in their documentation: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/workflow-actions-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-a-quick-reference-guide-HA010376961.aspx

Comment: if you want to have 14 days notification on the same list and on the same column (Due Date) how do you achieve this?