# Workflow send email on due date even after date changes

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, office-365

I must create a couple of Workflows, which will send notification to users (something like a reminder).

I have created a first WF that will be activated when item will be created or modified (SharePoint Online 2013).

WF-1
If State = New or Offer send and Email has not been sent then, pause until DeadlineDay = Today --> send email and change state to EmailHasBeenSent.

It's working fine, but if user will change the Deadline date The new WF will be created (maybe) and previously WF are still working. I don't know how to stop this WF.

Example:
Deadline = 25.09.2013 WF will set this date to send email. If I change date to Deadline = 30.09.2013 Email will be sent on 25.09.2013.

How can I do WF that will be check every day is the date has been change?

I try this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/aeaba6e9-1d13-4876-b012-53d32324909e/send-email-if-todaydue-date

and

[How to send mail every quarter till expiry date using sharepoint designer workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61823/how-to-send-mail-every-quarter-till-expiry-date-using-sharepoint-designer-workfl)

Second WF if similar but sends an email two days before the Deadline -> 2DaysBeforeDeadline.

Can you help me design this WF (step-by-step)?

Answer (score 2):

If you use SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online (Office 365):

You can create workflow which will only start when item created. Then pause it not until due date, but for one day. Thus your workflow will wake up each day and check due date, then send e-mail if needed.

Another approach with less performance cost is to schedule only one site level workflow which will query your tasks one time per day using CAML query. Thus you will be able to get all overdue tasks using one workflow action, then you can iterate through them and send e-mail notifications. This approach can be used only with 3rd party workflow action like [Get items by query](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/docs/actions-description/#GetItems) developed by my team. It is a part of paid set of extended workflow actions [Workflow Actions Pack.](http://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/)

Answer (score 0):

In this blog, you can write the mail-address to the log,

Declare due date =29/02/2016 & minus 7 days stored in date variable

This remainder mail through users or author of the item,

Site workflow

[Please click Here](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2016/02/before-days-send-reminder-mail.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a workflow to start when item is created or modified. This work flow check whether the date is due by comparing due date field with current date. If it is not due, set the workflow to pause for 1 day then modify any field in the list (you can create a field that does nothing but just for this purpose). Once modified, the workflow terminates but the modification will trigger another workflow, that workflow will check the due date again and pause for another day until the due date is matched.